# HazelcastGrid Computing EntryProcessor Executed on every Member

Tags: hazelcast, grid-computing

i have a problem with hazelcast using EntryProcessor or ExecutorService. If the key not exist in any member the Processor is still executed in each node and i don't understand why?

The processor receives key entry to null.

UPDATE with some code

```
    //example of IMap executeOnKeys
    Map<?, ?> map = getCache().executeOnKeys(keys, processor);

    //example using executor service
    Future<Object[]> result = executor.submitToKeyOwner(myCallable, key);
```

Processor

```
public class MyProcessor implements EntryProcessor<MyKey, MyValue>, Serializable {
...code
}
```

Callable

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Object[]>, Serializable {
...code
}
```

Two examples makes every node of the cluster receive the requests. If they haven't the key, the process is triggered and that's the problem.

I'm sending the request from a Lite member that is part of the cluster.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you call the EntryProcessor or ExecutorService? Any example code? If you do what I guess that sounds like a bug but please share some code first.

Comment: Added some code, i think now it's better. Thanks!

Comment: You send this request to a lite member? Still not 100% sure I got it. A lite member doesn't have any key at all, so how do you make sure the given key will end up at the lite member? What you're looking for is probably the Member addressing: `executor.submitToMember(callable, member)`

Comment: I send from a Lite Member to the cluster, and on each Processor i've put a log to check what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntryProccessor doesn't check if the key exists. It is something like a stored procedure and in theory can also create new key-value pairs. That said you can send an EntryProcessor to a key that doesn't exist yet and you would be able to store a new, just generated value.

You can, however, check if there's a value in the entry and if not you can expect the key to not yet exist and skip processing (if that helps) :-)